# Why do particles moving in circular motion emit em radiation?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation, centripetal-force

For example particles moving in a synchrotron . Which energy of the particle is converted to the energy of the radiation ? What is the relation between this energy and the change in direction of the particle?. 
Thankyou for the help .

Comment: Don't you think a synchrotron is using energy that doesn't come from the particle?

Comment: charges emit radiation when they change their velocity, i.e. accelerate.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Kinetic energy and photon absorption**

Particles - when moving into a magnetic field - have gained before kinetic energy. As [GRB wrote](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/237305/46708w):

> Every time a charged particle has to be accelerated, a photon has to be involved. If you want to linearly accelerate a charged particle, you have to shoot photons at its back.

To be precise this one of the possibilities of accelerating electrons, the second is the acceleration between a electric potential difference. It seems to be natural that electrons in the case of de-acceleration (braking) will re-emit photons. In other words, electrons have the possibility to absorb and to emit photons, the first happens in accelerations the second during braking.

**Intrinsic spin, magnetic dipole moment and gyroscopic effect**

The electron has a permanent magnetic dipole moment and an aligned with it intrinsic spin. As we know from Stern-Gerlach-experiment the spin has indeed to do with a momentum.

A electron at rest in a magnetic field will be aligned. Not spectacular. A moving electron in a magnetic field will be aligned too. But this time the straight line of the trajectory over goes to a spiral path which in reality is a path of tangerine slices. What happens?

The alignment of the electrons magnetic dipole moment lead to the deflection of the moving electron and this acceleration (every (non-gravitational) movement in circles is an acceleration) lead to the emission of photons. The photon has a momentum and this disaligne the electrons magnetic dipole moment again (gyroscopic effect). This process runs in cycles until the electron comes to rest.

I apologise for my bad English.